# unix egrep not matching a certain group

Tags: regex, unix, grep, grouping

I have this textfile

6 times: 5 capitals, split by a space

```
EWTLE YQTCE FNTMA YVTMB GWTDH QGTAL
UVGEV SPGWP HDAVZ FLRVY HVBFT OFUSG
UKAYH BOAXR BLUSG YRMZT WAIMR BOCCX
BIUCZ KYUPP ECUZI PIURZ MXUMB RDUIG
ANAZW IVAYI QNHFN UPTHC YACTJ QPRLV
```

Using Unix command line, egrep. I need to check if the middle character is the same in every group (here 4th line).

I tried to reverse the results if one of the letters was NOT the same, using a group. But I can't find how to do it.

```
egrep -v '[A-Z]{2}([A-Z])[A-Z]{2}.*[A-Z]{2}§NOT GROUP 1§[A-Z]{2}' filename
```

How can i fill in the part between §?

The solution i have is too long, just repeating the same for every group

```
egrep '[A-Z]{2}([A-Z])[A-Z]{2} [A-Z]{2}\1[A-Z]{2} 
[A-Z]{2}\1[A-Z]{2} [A-Z]{2}\1[A-Z]{2} [A-Z]{2}\1[A-Z]{2} [A-Z]{2}\1[A-Z]{2}' filename
```

Answer (score 2):

This is slightly shorter and accomplishes the same thing:

`[A-Z]{2}([A-Z])[A-Z]{2} ([A-Z]{2}\1[A-Z]{2} ?){5}`

Test it here: https://www.regextester.com/

Comment: Thanks alot for the help! This is alot shorter. The site you linked me will help me alot in my studies!

Answer (score 0):

Using `-P` option (PCRE):

```
grep -P '^([A-Z]{2})([A-Z])(?1)(?: (?1)\2(?1)){5}$' file.txt
```

**Output:**

```
EWTLE YQTCE FNTMA YVTMB GWTDH QGTAL
BIUCZ KYUPP ECUZI PIURZ MXUMB RDUIG
```

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of line
  ([A-Z]{2})    # group 1, 2 uppercases
  ([A-Z])       # group 2, 1 uppercase
  (?1)          # same pattern as group 1 (i.e. 2 uppercases)
  (?:           # start non capture group
                # 1 space
    (?1)        # same pattern as group 1 (i.e. 2 uppercases)
    \2          # same content as group 2, same letter
    (?1)        # same pattern as group 1 (i.e. 2 uppercases)
  ){5}          # end group, must appear 5 times
$               # end of line
```